# How to print every Nth character of a string?

Tags: text-processing, sed

This line of code does exactly this except I want it to start at the first character not the 7th.

```
$ echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy | sed 's/.\{1,7\}\(.\{0,1\}\)/\1/g'
```

What I'm looking for is

```
19gow
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't actually explain what you need, but one way to get your desired output would be to select every 8<sup>th</sup> character. Something like this:

```
$ echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy | sed -E 's/(.).{0,7}/\1/g'
19gow
```

That substitution looks for and "captures" any character (`(.)`), then replaces it and the next 7 characters (or fewer, if there are less than 7 characters left) with itself. Effectively, this removes all but every 8<sup>th</sup> character.

Comment: thank you works perfect!!!

Comment: You're very welcome, @Dan! If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
$ set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
$ string=1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
$ print -r -- ${string//(#b)(?)?(#c,7)/$match[1]}
19gow
```

With `ksh93`:

```
$ string=1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
$ print -r -- "${string//@(?){,7}(?)/\1}"
19gow
```

`bash`, like `zsh` has copied `${var//pattern/replacement}` from ksh93 and a few of ksh's extended glob operators including `@(...)`, but not the `{x,y}(...)` one nor the back-reference in the replacement.

Those should work regardless of what character `$string` may contain, even the newline character.

A POSIX equivalent:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    len = length(string = ARGV[1])
    for (i = 1; i <= len; i += 8) result = result substr(string, i, 1)
    print result
  }' "$string"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy | sed 's/\(.\{0,1\}\).\{1,7\}/\1/g'
19gow
```

The original did:

```
s/               substitute
.\{1,7\}         upto 7 characters
\(.\{0,1\}\)     and then the next in a capture
/                replace by
\1               that what was captured
/g               globally, so as many times as possible
```

So, moving the capture group to the front instead of the end does exactly what you asked.

```
s/               substitute
\(.\{0,1\}\)     capture the first character
.\{1,7\}         match upto 7 characters
/                replace by
\1               that what was captured
/g               globally, so as many times as possible
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty straightforward to do in the shell:

```bsh
letters='' word=1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
for ((i=0; i<${#word}; i+=8)); do letters+=${word:i:1}; done
echo "$letters"  # => 19gow
```

Comment: Since the Q doesn't mention any specific shell it may be worth adding a compatibility note: this code works unmodified in bash and ksh93, seems to require `${word:$i:1}` (added a `$`) in zsh (it may be configurable, I wouldn't know), and doesn't work in dash, yash, busybox ash and pdksh derivatives (I tried mksh and oksh).

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
str="1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy"
awk '{for (i=1;i<=length;i=i+8) printf substr($0,i,1); printf "\n"}' <<< "$str"
19gow
```

Answer (score 1):

With Perl, using modulo arithmetic and `grep` to filter the indices:

```
$ echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy | 
    perl -F'' -nE 'say @F[grep { !($_%8) } 0..$#F]'
19gow
```

With implementations of awk that interpret an empty FS to mean treat every character as its own field:

```
$ echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy | 
    mawk -F '' '{while(length($0)>0){printf $1; $0=substr($0,9)} printf "\n"}'
19gow
```